# Did King David and his men living among the Philistines transition Israel into the iron age?

Tags: history, samuel-shmuel-book-of, israel, metals

Apparently, during the reign of Saul, Israel was not yet in its iron age.  See passage below, but Israel seems to be in the iron age during King David's reign.  Did David's men learn how to work with iron when they lived among the philistines while staying away from Saul? Are there specific references to support this, or is this only circumstantial speculation?

> 19No smith was to be found in all the land of Israel, for the Philistines were afraid that the Hebrews would make swords or spears. 20So all the Israelites had to go down to the Philistines to have their plowshares, their mattocks, axes, and colters sharpened. 21 The charge for sharpening was a pim for plowshares, mattocks, three-pronged forks, and axes, and for setting the goads. 22Thus on the day of the battle, no sword or spear was to be found in the possession of any of the troops with Saul and Jonathan; only Saul and Jonathan had them.
> --
> Jewish Publication Society. (1985). *Tanakh: The Holy Scriptures* (1 Samuel 13:19–22). Jewish Publication Society.

Comment: From a traditional perspective, the original audience of the Torah itself would have been at least somewhat familiar with metallurgic processes, otherwise Deut. 4:20 falls on ears that cannot comprehend its imagery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pasuk 19](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.13.19?lang=bi) states it clearly: the Pelishtim actively prevented Israel from working iron, as a form of subjugation:

> וְחָרָשׁ לֹא יִמָּצֵא בְּכֹל אֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל **כִּי־[אָמְרוּ] (אמר)
> פְלִשְׁתִּים** פֶּן יַעֲשׂוּ הָעִבְרִים חֶרֶב אוֹ חֲנִית׃
>
> Now there was no smith found throughout all the land of Yisra᾽el: **for the Pelishtim said, Lest the Hebrews make them swords or spears** (Koren translation)

[Rashi there](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_I_Samuel.13.19.1?lang=bi) clarifies that Israel had had an iron economy before the Pelishtim did this to them:

> וחרש לא ימצא. **לא היה מצוי בתחלת מלכות שאול**, כי הפלשתים המושלים בישראל,
> **העבירו כל חרשי ברזל מישראל**, פן יעשו כלי זיין להלחם:
>
> A blacksmith was not to be found. I.e., **was not available at the
> beginning of Shaul's reign**, because the Philistines who ruled over
> Yisroel, **eliminated all the iron smiths from Yisroel**, lest they make
> weapons to wage war (The Metsudah Tanach series, Lakewood, N.J translation)